# Trying to access the Visibility property to tell if sub report is visible

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I’m trying return different  values to a sub reports parameter based on if it visible
The following code works,

```
=iif ( true, Fields!PatientID.Value,”junk so it sql string will not work” )
```

Now I try to change it to the following so different values will be return so it sql

```
=iif ( commentsub!hidden,”junk so it sql string will not work” )
```

This does not work.  Is there a way to do this?
I also tried

```
=iif ( commentsub!visible,”junk so it sql string will not work” )
```

And

```
=iif ( commentsub. visible,”junk so it sql string will not work” )
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `IIF()` statement requires 3 parameters. There are 3 in the first so it works the others only have 2 so will not.

Your `IIF()` statements should take look similar to

```
=IIF([Condition to Check],[Do when condition true],[Do when condition false])
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx#DecisionFunctions